# Firebase Admin ~ EACCES: permission denied, cloud-functions-emulator.log

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-admin

I am seem to get this error when i try to serve or deploy from firebase admin.

`EACCES: permission denied, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-emulator/logs/cloud-functions-emulator.log'`

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, with node installed via nvm. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure that you're using a node installed by nvm?  Wouldn't it install node in your home directory rather than in /usr/local?

Comment: ya know you are right, i switched from the package manger version to nvm. i think i need to just completly remove npm or something. to get a clean start